# Is there a standardized way to migrate FIWARE NGSI-LD entity representations to NGSI-v2?

Tags: fiware-orion

I already found [this script](https://github.com/FIWARE/data-models/blob/master/tools/normalized2LD.py)  by the FIWARE-Community, which converts an NGSI-v2 normalized representation into an NGSI-LD representation.

Is there something similar for the opposite direction? I am aware that most of the steps can be done backwards. However, I am not sure about the usual procedure for converting back the `"type": "Property"` nodes.

E.g given an NGSI-v2 entity representation:

```
{
    "id": "Store:001",
    "type": "Store",
    "name": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "Checkpoint Markt"
    }
}
```

Running the script on this will lead to:

```
{
    "@context": [
        https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld"
    ],
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:Store:001",
    "type": "Store",
    "name": {
        "type": "Property,
        "value": "Checkpoint Markt"
    }
}
```

So in this case it is quite difficult to convert the `"type": "Property"` node back to `"type": "Text"`.

But given the following NGSI-v2 entity representation:

```
{
    "type": "Store",
    "id": "Store:002",
    "address": {
        "type": "PostalAddress",
        "value": {
            "streetAddress": "Friedrichstraße 44",
            "addressRegion": "Berlin",
            "addressLocality": "Kreuzberg",
            "postalCode": "10969"
        }
    }
}
```

will be converted to:

```
{
    "@context": [
        https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld"
    ],
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:Store:002",
    "type": "Store",
    "address": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": {
            "streetAddress": "Friedrichstra\u00dfe 44",
            "addressRegion": "Berlin",
            "addressLocality": "Kreuzberg",
            "postalCode": "10969",
            "type": "PostalAddress"
        }
    }
}
```

This is caused by a special case in the script:

```py
if attr['type'] == 'PostalAddress':
    ld_attr['value']['type'] = 'PostalAddress'
```

Wouldn't it be possible to extend all converted attributes with such a `"type": _`-pair in their value? Or is there a reason that this is restricted in the code to the type "PostalAddress" only? Otherwise, is there any norm for converting back these `"type": "Property"` nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in NGSI-LD but the conversion for this particular case could be solved this way:

- If the `Property` has a `type` within its `value` then use it for the attribute type in NGSIv2 (as in the "PostalAddress" case you show)
- If the `Property` hasn't any `type` within its `value` then use as attribute `type` the default type specified in [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) "Partial Representations" section. For instance, if `value` is `"Checkpoint Markt"` (which is a string) then attribute type in NGSIv2 will correspond to `"Text"`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to convert from NGSI-LD to NGSIv2.

NGSI-LD >> NGSIv2 ... It could be the case you may need to transform from NGSIv2 to NGSI-LD so that you are more interoperable, but the other way round ... you may need to rethink if that is sensible ...